# UX design case studies

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, design-process

I am looking for well-written and in-depth case study articles of real life UX designs. I'd like to read how other designers tackle design challenges, and how their designs solve those challenges. This can be on any type of UX designs, not limited to web/software.

What I'm not looking for:

- General design blog sites.
- Theoretical articles.
- Defintion of what UX is or is not.
- Conference site links

Comment: I found UX Magazine as good source: http://uxmag.com/

Comment: Why was this made community wiki? Community Wiki is no longer supposed to be used for "lists".

Answer (score 4):

You could do worse than pick up a copy of the book [User Centered Design Stories by Righi and James](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123706084). There are some good examples of real-world UCD stories/case studies across a number of different situations and using different UCD techniques - not specifically about individual designs per se (more the techniques involved) but there may be something in there you find useful?

Comment: I read through the preview pages and it looks very promising!

Answer (score 4):

[Ergonomics in Design: The Quarterly of Human Factors Applications](http://ingentaconnect.com/content/hfes/ergdes/trial) is a great resource for practical case-studies.

Here's an article from the Summer 2010 issue: [One Laptop Per Child: Polishing Up the XO Laptop User Experience](http://erg.sagepub.com/content/18/3/8.full.pdf+html)

Answer (score 2):

Is something like this a case study?

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/05/innovative-techniques-to-simplify-signups-and-logins/

The site looks at a bunch of great ideas on how to improve your login and signup forms with examples from existing websites.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest browsing the publications of the [Nielsen Norman Group](http://www.nngroup.com/):

http://www.nngroup.com/reports/

Answer (score 2):

Jensen Harris from Microsoft posted a number of detailed UX articles [on his blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160206165352/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/jensenh/) about MS Office 2007 during its development, in particular about the ribbon. Much of that has now been distilled down into his "Story of the Ribbon" presentation, which you can [view or download here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jensenh/the-story-of-the-ribbon).

Answer (score 1):

http://uxmyths.com/ has a lot of resources divided by topic. Plus it includes a lot of links to different studies

Comment: I'm aware of uxmtyhs. but I was really looking for an actual case study article, written by the designer.

Answer (score 1):

Designing this site: http://www.usabilitypost.com/2011/04/22/designing-ux-exchange/

Answer (score 0):

Baymard institute offer an E-commrece checkout usability report, which includes 7 case studies. (but it is rather specialized)

On Baymard.com you can also find some more useful resources.

[Link to the report](http://baymard.com/checkout-usability)

And here are 2 more case studies:

[UX Considerations When Designing Lens Hawk](http://baymard.com/blog/ux-considerations-designing-lenshawk)

[Redesigning The Counry Selector](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/10/redesigning-the-country-selector/)